# Fatal exception when building on release (dexguard) but not in debug

Tags: android, proguard, android-resources, dexguard

I have seen this is a common problem with devices on 4.4. I have read a bunch of other threads about the abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml and I have been able to solve the problem in debug but not in release. Could anyone help here?. Here the exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.tools.picturedraw, PID: 8136
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tools.picturedraw/com.blrapp.blrcommon.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
>                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
>                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
>                                                        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(:354)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(:193)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(:181)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(:689)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(:186)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(:77)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(:83)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.(:146)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(:28)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(:41)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(:193)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(:173)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(:511)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(:71)
>                                                        at com.blrapp.blrcommon.MainActivity.onCreate(:136)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
>                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
>                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
>                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
>                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700) 
>                                                        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(:354) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(:193) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(:181) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(:689) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(:186) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(:77) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(:83) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.(:146) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(:28) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(:41) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(:193) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(:173) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(:511) 
>                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(:71) 
>                                                        at com.blrapp.blrcommon.MainActivity.onCreate(:136) 
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My app/gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir { dirs '/Users/hexdump/Developing/Android/tools/dexguard/lib/' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath ':dexguard:'
}
}



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'dexguard'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tools.picturedraw"

    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    versionCode 384
    versionName "3.84"


    signingConfigs
            {
                release
                        {
                            def console = System.console();
                            if (console == null) {
                                print("Please execute release compilations from console. Use ./comiple.sh")
                            } else {
                                def password = System.console().readPassword("\n Enter keystore password: ")
                                storeFile file("../mykey.keystore")
                                storePassword = new String(password)
                                keyAlias "general"
                                keyPassword new String(password)
                            }
                        }
            }
}

buildTypes
        {
            release
                    {
                        //Use command line to compile in release
                        //minifyEnabled false
                        proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
                        //proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
                        proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
                        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

                    }
            debug
                    {
                        proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')
                        //proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
                        //proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
                    }
        }
productFlavors {
}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':adnetworks')
compile project(':coretools')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.2'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the version of support library dependencies. Change `23.2.1` to `23.4.0`:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':adnetworks')
compile project(':coretools')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.2'
}
```

**EDIT:**

> If you are having any support library dependency in any of your
>   modules("adnetworks" or "coretools"). Please change their versions to
>   the latest version as i have suggested.

I was facing the same problem and solved by **updating the version of libraries to the latest ones**.!!

Comment: my dependencies targeted this versions before... just started to play with them after don't knowing what to do :( and this is why I shown dependencies on 23.2.1. Oddly, I did a clean, exited android studio... and it worked! 2 wasted hours!. Anyway I will accept your answer.

Comment: Do you get any issues when updating to support 24.0.0+?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the accepted answer doesn't help in most cases, as it is really a DexGuard issue. After much research and debugging, I have finally got the correct answer, which I posted and explained at [DexGuard and Vector Drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003356/dexguard-and-vector-drawables)